# How to make loading animation gif invisiable on complete of getjson call and display jw player instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jwplayer

I want to show an loading animation on load of page and remove the loading animation when getjson called completes successfully and show my jw player code at end of getjson completion. Right now my loading animation is visible at all time. Could you guys show me how i can make the animation loading invisible at end of getjson call and show my jw player instead ?

My loading animation image:

```
<td rowspan="4"><img src="./loading.gif" width="304" height="287"></td>
```

and my getjson call:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('http://www.somesite.com/getmedia.php?id=1234&callback=?', function(data){
var mediaUrl = data.contents;
jwplayer().load({file: mediaUrl+".flv"});

});

</script>
```

jw player that should become visiable at end of getjson call:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': './player.swf',
    'autostart': 'true',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '470',
    'height': '320'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your img tag in id, like "loadingimg"... then, on your completion of the Ajax event:

```
$('#loadingimg').hide();
```

EDIT:
Also, the player should have a style of "display: none".  When you want to show it, call

```
$('#player').show();
```

or whatever ID you give the player...

EDIT:
Put these two lines in the callback function to getJSON(), after jwplayer.load();

Comment: Many thanks steve. The loading became invisible as the way i wanted but i dont know how i can make my jw player invisable at start and visiable at end !how i can add display:non to jw player? or if possible some how i show the loading gif over the player and remove it when getjson complets but dont know how to place it over player!Furthermore , is it possible to check if check for getjson response if it is empty i show some text to user or just reload the page or re call getjson ?(my goad is that getjson doesnt come empty)

Comment: Put the player in a DIV and set the style to none, either through the style attribute or through CSS:  <div id="playerWrapper" style="display:none"> ... player goes here... </div>

Comment: my advice is to get it all looking the way you want first, then add the JS to hide/show as needed.  Use Firebug or Chrome dev. tools to modify the CSS styles on the fly.  That way you can tweak them and get it the way you want, then just write code to toggle the styles.